# What are these CSS ... 'titles/selectors' called?

Tags: html, css

So when writing CSS, I often see people or websites have things like

```
.img > border > div > #select {color:white}
```

Since I have started web development, I have only used... single CSS classes.

I'm not sure that's entirely correct, but basically they are all connected.

What is the name of this technique, and do you guys have any useful resources I could read up about on this?
I did try and Google this pre-hand, but I simply didn't know how to word this on Google.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: `>` is a direct selector.. as far as resources, W3C documentation, and Mozilla Dev are helpful.

Comment: [css3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors) [css2 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire sequence `.img > border > div > #select` is usually simply called a [selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#rule-sets), since it's the part of the CSS rule that selects elements to apply the rule to. There is an entire [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors) devoted to selectors however; CSS just describes the role of a selector in a CSS rule.

`>` is a combinator, specifically the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators). Combinators are used to express relationships between two elements, in this case a parent-child relationship: `.parent > .child`. The rest, `.img`, `border`, `div` and `#select` are all [simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#simple-selectors) of various kinds.

A typical selector is made up of simple selectors and combinators. You can have a selector with just one simple selector `.child`, multiple simple selectors `div.child`, combinators `#parent > div.child`, or any combination of those.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [selector](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets/Selectors) and represents the HTML document element hierarchy that it applies to, i.e.

A class of image that has a border which has a div which has an ID of select, apply a color of white.

Answer (score 1):

The `>` sign is essentially a way of specifying that an element belongs to a parent element. In your case, the element with the id of "select" has a parent element that is a div that has a border that has a parent element that has a class of "img." More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp).

Answer (score 1):

These are known as child selectors.

It's covered in the [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors), and the whole guide itself is a good resource with simple examples.

Answer (score 0):

they're called CSS Selectors.
See here:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and brief explanation with the selector you provided

```
.img > border > div > #select {color:white}
```

The above CSS is a hierarchy of selector where, the rule is applied to #selector that is within div tag, border tag , and class .img

**For example**

```
<img class="img"><border><div><div id='select'>some content</div></div></border></img>
```

Here the above CSS rule is applied. Similarly rule can be created as follows

```
element>element
selector>selector
element>selector
selector>element
```

For more information check this out http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Hope this helps!

Comment: What do `element>element selector>selector element>selector selector>element` all mean?

Comment: in the above rules elements can be any HTML elements like p, body, div, etc. and selector can be any selector like id or class.

Comment: Aren't they all selectors anyway?

Comment: Got it? substitute any of the HTML elements in place of element and id or class in place of selector and hierarchy can be of any length.

Comment: yep, those are examples for, how to use them.